# Bottle mishandling JSON data in Python3, but not Python2

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, bottle, python-3.4

I've got a bottle-based HTTP server that mostly shuffles JSON data around. When I run this in Python 2.7 it works perfectly, and in my route handlers I can access the JSON data via `bottle.request.json`. However, when I run it under Python 3.4 `bottle.request.json` is `None`.

I've examined the HTTP traffic, and in both cases it is exactly the same (as would expected since that's under control of the non-Python-dependent client.)

I also see that the JSON data *is* reaching bottle in both cases. If I print out `bottle.request.params.keys()`, I see the string-ified JSON as the only entry in the list in both cases. And the strings are identical in both cases. For some reason, however, the Python 2 version is recognizing the JSON data while the Python 3 version isn't.

Strangely, this used to work, but some recent change either in my code or bottle (or both) has broken things. Looking over my code, though, I can't see what I might have done to create the problem.

Does anyone know what's going on? Is this something I'm doing wrong at the client end, at the bottle configuration end, or is this a bottle defect? I searched for this problem both on google and the bottle issue tracker, but to no avail.

Comment: Does the client set the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Yes, Content-Type is properly set.

Comment: _"`bottle.request.json`. However, when I run it under Python 3.4 `bottle.json.request` is `None`"_ - `.request.json != .json.request` - is this a typo?

Comment: Err, yes, I mistyped that. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to have nothing to do with bottle. The ultimate cause of the problem is that the client request has two `Content-Type` headers due to a [defect in an emacs lisp HTTP library](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request/pull/15). Embarrassingly, I've known about this defect for quite some time, but I thought I'd properly worked around it.

I'm not 100% sure why I see the variance between Python 2 and 3, but my guess right now is that it has to do with otherwise benign changes in the WSGI machinery between the versions.